# How to upload a custom theme for your BigCartel store?

Tags: bigcartel

I am using the dugway CLI tool to develop my theme. When I do `dugway build`, it creates a zip file. What am I supposed to do with this?

I see no mention of this in the [theme development docs](https://help.bigcartel.com/developers/themes/), and I can't see any 'upload theme' form anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it's not possible to upload a theme directly from Dugway to Big Cartel, you'll need to copy/paste the theme code into the appropriate section in Customize Design > Advanced - and any assets like javascript or image files will need to be hosted separately. https://github.com/bigcartel/dugway#known-issues--limitations

Comment: Thanks. Any idea when there will be a way to just drop in a zip file?

Comment: Unfortunately there's not any timeline in place for that yet, but it is being planned for the future.